# granting privileges to user

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-grant

I want that table created by one user should be accessible to another user also
I am doing the following thing.

Connect to user2
connected

```
    SQL>grant SELECT on INFO to user1;   //info is a table created by user2
    SQL>grant succeeded
```

connect to user1;
connected

```
    SQL>select * from INFO;
```

Then it returns the error

```
     select * from INFO
                   *
     error at line1:
     ora 00942: table or view does not exist
```

Please help me

Comment: You have to qualify table name with schema name, like so: `select * from user2.INFO` Otherwise the table name is resolved to your current schema, which is `user1` and there is no `info` table in it

Comment: understood the difference. there can be even possibilities that both user have same table name so we always have to use the schema along with the table.

Comment: @user3136186 If you want to omit schema name in your queries then you can create public synonym and grant user1 access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try executing your query like this: **user2** is the Schema here..

```
select * from user2.INFO
```

Hope it helps..